# How to filter out items in query?

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library

`ReadSensorsAsync` will return sometimes null `Result`.

```
 var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));
 var tasksRecord = tasksRead.Select(x => RecordReadingAsync(x.Result));
```

How can I filter those tasks out so in second query I process only non-null items?

Comment: Check my post and the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a Where in the second statement:

```
 var tasksRead = Enumerable
   .Range(3, 35)
   .Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));

 var tasksRecord = tasksRead
   .Where(x => x.Result != null)
   .Select(x => RecordReadingAsync(x.Result));
```

Comment: Just be warned that this solution can cause deadlock if you execute this code on UI thread and `ReadSensorsAsync` internally does another async call without setting `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It would be best to mark containing method as `async` and use `await` keyword instead.

Comment: Fortunately app is running as Windows Service. The routines are within `Threading.Timer` callback. But thanks for proper heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 var tasksRecord = from tr in Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(ReadSensorsAsync)
                       where tr != null select RecordReadingAsync(tr.Result);
```

Comment: But Pablo if it is with real Async call you have to consider using the plain version of Dmitry Bychenko and the use of await for tasks.Now your sample seems to be wrong. Also maybe you have to change the title of the posts as it includes async calls ..

Comment: I've just added TPL in tags. I don't need to use `async` because I don't see point in making timer callback `async`.Just to use thread pool.

Comment: Ok,you can use my approach too.

Comment: Also the answer was not from Dmitry Bychenko, but from @3615.

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake.I mean @3615